# Is there a way to get the ForeignKeyDependents of an EF entity?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there a way to get the ForeignKeyDependents of an EF entity?

Comment: You should explain your question little bit more. At least for me it is not clear what you are asking for?

Comment: i want to get the foreigns keys that the entity is dependent on

Comment: there is a property in System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySet called ForeignKeyDependents but is is declared as friend.